# How to do an alert after appending elements to container using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendto

I append some text to a container, and alert user after successful append like;

```
$("SomeTextToAppend").appendTo(".container",function(){
  alert("appended");
});
```

But alert is not working. Appending is fine. Also, I would like to know how to do the same using `append()` function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs `appendTo()` doesn't accept a second argument.

you would have to do something like:

```
$("SomeTextToAppend").appendTo(".container");
alert("appended");
```

Doing it the other way around with `append()` would look more like

```
$(".container").append("SomeTextToAppend");
```

Hope this helps